# Printing data into a preprinted form in C# .Net 3.5 SP1

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I need to print out data into a pre-printed A6 form (1/4 the size of a landsacpe A4). I do not need to print paragraphs of text, just short lines scattered about on the page.

All the stuff on MSDN is about priting paragraphs of text.

Thanks for any help you can give,
Roberto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When finding the x,y coordinates to use for lining up your new text with the pre-printed gaps, the default settings for the graphics object's Draw____() functions are 100 pixels per inch.  That might be subject to change based on your printer, but in my (very limited) experience that's always been the case.

Answer (score 2):

you'll have to create a PrintDocument object, handle the at least the PrintPage event and apply the appropriate changes to the PrinterSettings property.

In your PrintPage event handler, do whatever you need to do with the PringPageEventArgs.Graphics object; like drawing lines, drawing images, etc.